# R: Summing POSIXct-objects using tapply

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to sum a set of POSIXct objects by a factor variable, but am getting an error that `sum` is not defined for POSIXt objects. However, it works fine if I just calculate the mean. But how can I get the summed times by group using tapply?

Example:

```
data <- data.frame(time = c("2:50:04", "1:24:10", "3:10:43", "1:44:26", "2:10:19", "3:01:04"),
                   group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"))
data$group <- as.factor(data$group)
data$time <- as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", data$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")

# works
tapply(data$time, data$group, mean)

# doesn't work
tapply(data$time, data$group, sum)
```

Comment: try `tapply(data$time, data$group, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: Great, this is the simple kind of workaround I was hoping for. Only needs converting back into a h:m:s format, which is pretty straight forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date objects cannot be summed, this does semantically not make sense, the `+` operator is also not defined for POSIXct objects.

Probably you want to model time differences and sum them up?

Try:

```
times <- as.difftime(c("2:50:04", "1:24:10", "3:10:43", 
                       "1:44:26", "2:10:19", "3:01:04"), "%H:%M:%S")
sum(times)
```

A `difftime` object is also that what you get when you subtract two date objects (which is semantically reasonable).

**EDIT:**

A entire solution for the OPs problem in a semantically neater way (tapply seams to destroy the structure of the difftime class - use `group_by` from the dplyr package instead)

```
library(dplyr)

times <- as.difftime(c("2:50:04", "1:24:10", "3:10:43", 
                       "1:44:26", "2:10:19", "3:01:04"), format="%H:%M:%S")

data <- data.frame(time = times, group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"))

summarise(group_by(data, group), sum(time))
```

This gives the following output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  group      sum(time)
1     A 7.415833 hours
2     B 6.930278 hours
```

Comment: Hmm, your code does seem to provide what I'm after, but I'm not sure I completely understand the difference between POSIXct and difftime. Could you show me how this would be implemented in a tapply from the original POSIXct data?

Comment: Thanks, your edit helped my understanding a lot. Though I think tapply should still work without involving dplyr if I make a copy of my time variable in the difftime format. Then `tapply(times, data$group, sum)` should provide the same result. Edit: And it does, so I marked the question as solved.